# How to bind clear to ^L in Ksh

Tags: ksh

How can i replicate the following bash functionality in KornShell:

```sh
bind "\C-l":"clear-screen"
```

I needed that `bind` because i'm using `set -o vi` in bash, and
plan on using it in ksh too.

Trying to use it in ksh prints out an error:

```
ksh: bind: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to break the news, but as you've noticed this a different between ksh and bash: bind or the ability to define key mappings is not there. Nor is programmable command completion. Historically the Korn shell focused on language design and features and not on interactive terminal capabilities.

GNU bash provides key bindings via the GNU Readline library which was developed and maintained by the same person, Chet Ramey. `ksh` even in its most recent versions doesn't use this library nor does it provide an equivalant library, as far as I know.

A workaround is to see if you can program the terminal to provide such capabilities. In tmux if you put this in your `.tmux.conf` configuration file:

```
bind-key C-l send-keys clear
```

Then tmux will interpret the Control-l before `ksh` has a chance to see it and will expand with the string "clear".  (Underneath I bet tmux is using the GNU Readline library)

The POSIX standard (which ksh and bash both follow) defines an "alias" command. However an alias name [isn't defined to allow control characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_10). A particular implemenation may do that, but ksh doesn't.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82223/how-to-setup-keyboard-shortcut-that-enters-predefined-text-into-x11-xterminal-vi